# SharePoint reading wrong resource file

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-site, resource-files

I have a publishing site with following structure

```
Top level site  
   English  
       ENSubsite  
   Arabic  
       ARSubsite
```

The "Locale" in "Regional Settings" of English and ENSubsite is set to English (United Kingdom) while for Arabic and ARSubsite it is set to Arabic (Saudi Arabia).

I have the following resource files in App_Globalresources folder

mysite.resx
mysite.en-GB.resx
mysite.ar-SA.resx

The code to read resource file is written in page layout. When I open English site website then it reads it from mysite.en-GB.resx

When I open Arabic site then it reads from mysite.ar-SA.resx

In both cases above it is fine.

But when I read ENSubsite or ARSubsite, in both cases it reads from mysite.resx

Because of this reason both ENSubsite and ARSubsite are showing same text.

Why is it reading from same resource file?